# Using express to render views in Angular 10?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Is it possible to use express to render views in Angular 10 rather than using the Angular Router? My team is in the process of upgrading from Angular.js to Angular 10 and we used express with the dust.js templating engine to render the views in the Angular.js app.

The current logic is as follows:
Upload all individual pages (html, css, and js file) to a file system -> when page route is hit, fetch these files -> insert content into dust.js templates -> render templates on server side

Our goal is to render Angular pages server side, with the capability of making quick changes to certain pages (by changing individual files on the filesystem) without having to rebuild the entire application every time a change is needed. Is it possible to continue doing this in the new Angular app or would it be bad practice?

Comment: It's not directly related, but how oftten do you need to change those fiels and how big are the changes, are you just changing static texts or you are changing the whole structure?

Comment: Angular is meant to be built as a single page application using the angular router to route pages. Using express for each route would be huge overhead.

Comment: @ХристиянХристов We change around images/text/ordering but the entire structure largely remains the same. These changes happen around once to twice per month.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I see. Would you say it is better to not use Angular for our use case? My concern is that the team is already familiar with Angular and the old angular.js templates are at least somewhat reusable so some overhead would be an OK tradeoff.

Comment: The way angular works is it bundles the whole project as one. So for every page request you will be sending the entire application to the user anyways, so why waste the time doing the routing on the server... If you want to send each page to the user as a single page, you need to make individual angular apps for each page and bundle them each separately which would be a pain to manage, and you then lose the ability of component sharing.

Comment: I see, that definitely does not sound worth it. Seems like I and my team had a misunderstanding on how Angular worked. Tyvm for the explanation!

Comment: Angularjs and Angular 2+ work in almost completely different ways from one another. In angularjs it was the norm to do what you describe, but Angular2, that is not common practice.